# How to execute Action Filter before Authorization Filter MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

I have implemented my own custom Authorization Attribute in MVC 4 by inheriting from `AuthorizeAttribute` class. I also have a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`. These both work fine however the problem lies in ordering them. I need the custom Action Filter to run before the custom Authorize Filter.

I have tried using the `Order` property for the attributes but as i understand it, Authorize Filters will always run before Action Filters.

Does anyone know how to force the Action Filter to execute before the Authorize Filter??

Comment: The Authorize Filter checks to see if the user has permission, there's no point checking anything else if they don't. It sounds like you're doing something odd. Perhaps explain why you want to swap them.

Comment: Well the Action Filter checks whether a particular user has a temporary password so i want them to be redirected to a "Change Password" page before it comes up and says "Unauthorized". Hope that makes sense...

Comment: In that case it sounds like you want people with temporary passwords to fail the Authorize check still, but simply want to check in your "Unauthorized" page if they have a temp password, and redirect to the "Change Password" page in that case. Alternatively, you could catch this at login and force them to change their password before you allow them to login. Then you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you take a look at the source code (available at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/) you see that this is not possible with the standard Filter classes. `IAuthorizationFilter` implementations are always executed before `IActionFilter` implementations. That's because action filters will not run when authorization filters return a result.

To solve this you can create your own `ControllerActionInvoker` descendant class and override the `InvokeAction` method:

```
public class MyControllerActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    public override bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
    {
        // Your initialization code here
        try
        {
            return base.InvokeAction(controllerContext, actionName);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Your finalization code here
        }
    }
}
```

You need to inject your custom `MyControllerActionInvoker` class into your controllers in a custom `ControllerFactory` class:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly MyControllerActionInvoker actionInvoker = new MyControllerActionInvoker();

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the controller instance for the specified request context and controller type.
    /// </summary>
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var controllerInstance = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);

        if (controllerInstance != null)
        {
            var typedController = controllerInstance as Controller;
            if (typedController != null)
            {
                typedController.ActionInvoker = this.actionInvoker;
            }
        }

        return controllerInstance;
    }
}
```

And of course you now have to register your own `MyControllerFactory` with the MVC framework. You should do this where you're also registering your routes:

```
var controllerFactory = new MyControllerFactory();
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

This implementation works fine here.