# Change default order of Filters within ASP.Net MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there anyway to force a custom IActionFilter to execute before a custom IAuthenticationFilter?

I'm familiar with the following documentation on filter ordering:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

But I'm wondering if I can change it at all. I've implemented a custom IFilterProvider like the following but can't make my authorization filter (IAuthorizationFilter) execute after the UnitOfWork (IActionFilter).

```
public class CustomFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return new List<Filter>
        {
            new Filter(new UnitOfWork(), FilterScope.Global, 0),
            new Filter(new CustomAuthorization(), FilterScope.Global, 30),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496561/how-to-execute-action-filter-before-authorization-filter-mvc-4

Comment: As the linked article states _"Authorization filters run before any other filter"_ which makes sense - why would you bother to run code if your not authorized to do so. But I guess you could create a custom Authorization filter that does what you want

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want the UnitOfWork to happen before as it is responsible for opening a db connection and maintaining its transaction scope. I have authorization filters that need to query the db so this work needs to be done before the authorization. I do realize I could move the unit of work somewhere else.

Comment: Filters are the absolute WORST place to be doing database activity.  Apart from the fact that this is deep in the pipeline of your presentation layer (data accession should be well below your business layer), you have very little control over when they are created or destroyed and this is terrible for something where you need to clean up the resources.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Are you saying your opposed to having a Unit Of Work within a filter or are you saying that authorization filters should never access a database? I'm leaning towards moving my Unit Of Work outside of a filter but my authorization must access a db.

Comment: No, your authorization *filter* should not access your database.  You seem stuck on the idea that your database access must occur at the same place you do your filtering.  That is not the case.  Consider how the default Authorize filter works.  It does it's work earlier in the pipeline and sets the IPrincipal to the required data.  The Authorization filter need only check the IPrincipal, as the work has already been done.  In fact, I almost always question the need for a custom authorization filter, as most often you can simply use your own IPrincipal and/or IIdentity implementations

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Interesting. We have some complex authorization going on and often need to check the db for access. I'm not quite sure how we could get around that but I'll think about your response some more. I'm curious why you say in your previous comment that "you have very little control over when they are created or destroyed". Although you may be right that I have little control over this I do know when filters are created and used within the pipeline so I can control how I use them. Do you have a reference to a resource that explains your comment more thoroughly?

Comment: @GaryBrunton - you're still not listening... I didn't say you can't do database access.  I said you shouldn't do it in your filter.  You do it elsewhere, and your filter is just used as a simple logic to test the variables that have been set by your "complex logic" elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears as though the best you can do is order Filters within Filter types unless you wanted to override the ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction method and completely change the default MVC pipeline for these things.

I've found Filters to be unpleasant to use. Wish they would have been implemented as decorators on top of actions so that we could wrap functionality around them easier.